# Windows Server 2003: Need Security Tips and DNS Info

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003

Can someone give me Windows 2003 security tips, simple steps to secure the server and also how to setup ns1/ns2 name servers on the box?

Comment: You are going to need to provide a lot more context if you are hoping to receive a useful answer.  It sounds like you are planning to use this server to host an internet-facing domain, but that is just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

As far as securing the server is concerned, I think the best method is to run the Security Configuration Wizard after you've installed and configured the roles\services that the server is going to provide.